# Expansion of double integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I've come across this deceptively difficult integral:

$$I(t)=\frac{e^{4t}}{t^2}\int_1^\infty dx\int_1^\infty dy\frac{e^{-2t(x+y)}}{(4xy-1)^2},$$

and I want to study its behavior around $t\rightarrow0^+$. I found a simple series expression in terms of exponential integrals, but it doesn't seem to help much:

$$I(t)=\frac{e^{4t}}{t^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+1}{4^{n+2}}E_{n+2}^2(2t).$$

What are the typical tricks and techniques to handle this sort of problem? I expect that there will be terms like $1/t^2$ and $1/t$ with some factors of $\log(2t)$ and constant bits, but precisely extracting them has proven to be a challenge. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just out of curiosity : could you tell about the steps ? The inner integral is doable but next ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, just simplify the integral wrt $y$ inside the double integral. You will get the summation form.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I think the easiest way to find the series I have written above is to rewrite so that the denominator is $(1-1/(4xy))^2$ and express this as a geometric series. Then the double integral is simply the squared integral expression for the exponential integral. If you try to brute-force it by performing either the $x$ or $y$ integral first, you will end up with an integral over rational functions times inverse hyperbolic functions with rational arguments.

Comment: After some effort one can arrive at the following formula. $$\frac{e^{4t}}{t^2}(\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2t(x+1)}}{(4x)(4x-1)}- \frac{2t}{(4x)^2}e^{-2tx}Ei(2t(\frac{1}{4x}-1))dx$$

Comment: The first expression in the integrand has an anti derivative in terms of elementary functions. But the second one doesnt have any. So we are required to do any step using that limit sign in front. I don't know if we directly bring in limit sign inside the integral but if we can then we are done.

Comment: The denominator in your series should be $4^{n+2}$. Since $\operatorname{E}_k (0) = (k-1)^{-1}$ for $k \geq 2$, the leading term obtained by summing the series of constants is $\frac{\log(4/3)}{4 t^2}$. The next term (due to $\operatorname{E}_2$) is $\frac{\log(2t)}{4 t}$ and then there should be a $t^{-1}$-contribution.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, thank you. I think I just  absorbed it into the overall constant coefficient of this integral in my notes.

Answer (score 3):

The following is not rigorous, and maybe someone can improve it.  The approximation will come from an alternative representation,
$$H(a,t):=\int_1^\infty dx \, \int_1^\infty dy \, \frac{ \exp{\big(-2t(x+y)\big)} }{ (a+4xy)^2 } $$
$$ = \frac{1}{4}\int_0^\infty  \exp{\big(-au+t^2/u\big)} \Gamma(0,\frac{(t+2u)^2}{u} ) \, du $$  where the incomplete gamma function can be connected to the exponential function Ei function through
$$\Gamma(0,x) = -\text{Ei(-x)}. $$
The OP's problem is solved by setting $a=-1.$
The proof is not difficult. Use the Gauss integral for $1/(a+4xy)^2,$
$$\int_0^\infty u \, e^{-bu} du = 1/b^2, $$
interchange integrals, let Mathematica do the innermost double integral, and simplify.  The equivalence has been checked numerically for several real $a$ and $t.$  Here is where the non-rigor enters.  There are several representations for Ei(-x) that have a leading $e^{-x}$ factor, e.g., Gradshteyn and Ryzhik 8.212.[3-14] and even the asymptotic form has such a leading factor.  If we used such a formula, then
$$  \exp{\big(-au+t^2/u\big)} \Gamma(0,\frac{(t+2u)^2}{u} ) \approx 
\exp{\big(-au+t^2/u  -(t^2/u + 4t+4u)   \big)} (something) $$
where *something* should be well-behaved.  The $t^2/u$ terms, which diverge at the origin, are thus cancelled.  (This also justifies the above formal manipulations as long as $a>-4.$) We are therefore left with the much easier to analyze

$$ H(a,t) \approx \frac{1}{4}\int_0^\infty  \exp{\big(-au)} \Gamma(0, 4t+4u) \, du :=\hat{H}(a,t) $$
Shift the argument in $\hat{H},$
$$4\hat{H}(a,t)=\exp{(at)}\int_t^\infty   \exp{\big(-au)} \Gamma(0, 4u) \,du =$$
$$=\exp{(at)}\Big( \int_0^\infty   \exp{\big(-au)} \Gamma(0, 4u)\,du
- \int_0^t\exp{\big(-au)} \Gamma(0, 4u) \,du \Big) $$
The first integral is solvable in closed form.  Since $t \to 0,$ $u$ is small and so approximate the exponential with the constant 1. That integral is solvable as well.  We find that
$$4\hat{H}(a,t) \sim \exp{(at)}\Big( \frac{\log{(1+a/4)}}{a} -(\frac{1}{4}(1-e^{-4t}) + t\Gamma(0, 4t)) \Big) $$
$$\sim \exp{(at)}\Big( \frac{\log{(1+a/4)}}{a} -t (1+ \Gamma(0, 4t)) \Big) $$

One can expand $\Gamma(0, 4t) \sim -(\gamma + \log{4} +\log{t})$ to see that the next to leading order has a $t \log{t}$ dependence.

With $a=-1,$ I did some numerical comparisons with the 2nd equation of the answer vs. the approximation of the preceding formula for $\hat{H}(-1,t)$ for $t=0.01, 0.001,$ and $0.0001.$  The respective errors are 2.0%, 0.23%, and 0.024%, respectively.  I don't think further terms are available via this method until the *something* mentioned in the middle of the answer is quantified.